# Convert ".po" to ".pot" file

Tags: gettext

I'm trying to convert ".po" to ".pot" file.
I found this command but it does not work for me...

```
msgfilter -i name.po -o new.pot true
```

(msgfilter and name.po I have the same folder)

I tested it but it does not work either

```
msgfilter -i C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\test\bin\name.po -o C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\test\bin\new.pot true
```

I use:

- Windows 7
- https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html

Please help me thx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a new .pot template from a translated .po file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938869/how-to-generate-a-new-pot-template-from-a-translated-po-file)